# PHP json_decode returns null from string

Tags: javascript, php, json

Right now I'm doing an app that saves a series of coordenates from Google Maps into a hidden input and then I get data from a form to PHP, it outputs ok, but when I try to read the string and decode the JSON it returns NULL.

Right now this is my Javascript code:

```
var bounds = []; 
var bound = {};
polygon.getPaths().forEach(function(punto, indice){
     punto.forEach(function(puntoX, indice){
           bound = {'lat': puntoX.lat(), 'lng': puntoX.lng()};
           bounds.push(bound);

     });
});
$('#bounds').val(JSON.stringify(bounds));
```

HTML code:

```
<form class="signup-block" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?c=create"; ?>">
<button id="save" class="button success disabled" type="submit" disabled>Crear Geocerca</button>
<br>
<h3>Datos de la geocerca</h3>
<label for="nombre">Nombre de la geocerca:</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required />
<label for="tipo">Tipo de geocerca:</label>
<input type="text" id="tipo" name="tipo" readonly />
<div id="registro"></div>
<input id="bounds" type="hidden" name="bounds" />
```

This is the bounds input with values after assigned by JS

```
<input id="bounds" type="hidden" name="bounds" value="[{&quot;lat&quot;:-2.1585226452743442,&quot;lng&quot;:-79.8945227265358},{&quot;lat&quot;:-2.1670138304221926,&quot;lng&quot;:-79.9018183350563},{&quot;lat&quot;:-2.176963037271158,&quot;lng&quot;:-79.8945227265358},{&quot;lat&quot;:-2.1733607458083646,&quot;lng&quot;:-79.875468313694},{&quot;lat&quot;:-2.1587799546129793,&quot;lng&quot;:-79.8783865571022}]">
```

The PHP code:

```
$bounds =filter_input(INPUT_POST,"bounds", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (!$bounds) {
     $this->error['error'] = 'Parametros incorrecto';
}else{
     $coords = json_decode($bounds);
     echo var_dump($bounds);//Outputs something
     echo var_dump($coords);//Outputs null
```

I have checked and the $bounds variable get the values, but it fails to read them as JSON, what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the output of both var_dumps
Output of $bounds

```
string(408) "[{"lat":-2.1581795660883976,"lng":-79.90096002817154},{"lat":-2.171559596852916,"lng":-79.9018183350563},{"lat":-2.176448424731824,"lng":-79.89057451486588},{"lat":-2.1662419064644722,"lng":-79.88053232431412},{"lat":-2.156206859267206,"lng":-79.8930636048317},{"lat":-2.15835110569104,"lng":-79.90164667367935}]"
```

Output of $coords

```
NULL
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with this code: https://3v4l.org/67681

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it seems it happens when getting values from INPUT POST

Comment: @rjdown it outputs error syntax O.o but this JSON generated with JSON.stringify of javascript, I will edit this question to show the generated HTML

Comment: Are you sure the output you posted is what you are getting?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara besided var_dump how else could I verify that? Whats odd is the generated HTML, I think copying it from console results in that

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is on the same situation as I am, the problem is that the HTML output prints all the " and ' as html entities, so this is necessary to do first

```
$bounds = html_entity_decode($bounds);
$coords = json_decode($bounds, true);
echo var_dump($coords);
```

It took me a really long time analyzing page output on different ways

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all.  HTML has nothing to do with the value of the input, nor the POST data encoding.  I'm not convinced this is your actual problem, unless there's more to the story here.

Comment: Mmm perhaps but I tried other things like utf8 encoding. Only when I printed this as plain text output on a different file I noted that the ' characters where printed as %quote or something similar

Comment: How were you printing it though?  First, check the data actually being sent to the server, using your browser's developer tools.  If the actual form data has HTML entities in it, the problem is in your JavaScript.  If it doesn't, then something server-side is really mangling your data unnecessarily.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:
jsondecode($bounds,true)

Comment: That's strange,look at here:

Comment: string '[{"lat":-2.1581795660883976,"lng":-79.90096002817154},{"lat":-2.171559596852916,"lng":-79.9018183350563},{"lat":-2.176448424731824,"lng":-79.89057451486588},{"lat":-2.1662419064644722,"lng":-79.88053232431412},{"lat":-2.156206859267206,"lng":-79.8930636048317},{"lat":-2.15835110569104,"lng":-79.90164667367935}]' (length=312)  replace the " wiht '

Comment: you may turn on<br/>ini_set('display_errors','on');error_reporting(E_ALL);<br/>To see what happens

Comment: how do I replace that? It is generated from Javascript with JSON.stringify

Comment: Sorry i'm not famililar with the javascript,since the data comes from the form,the function .serializeArray()  or .serialize() may help.(jquery function).....for the worst ,you can replace the " by php code,such as substr_replace()